# Why DLV finds an answer set rather than another, in this ASP example program?

Tags: logic-programming, answer-set-programming

I tried two simple programs in ASP(Answer Set Programming) and then i used the answer set solver DLV to find the answer sets (also referred as stable models); the programs are

P1:

```
b :- c.  
c.
```

P2:

```
b :- c.  
f.
```

in P1 dlv finds {c, b} as answer set, in P2 the answer set found is {f}; i can't understand why the answer set is {c,b} in P1, and is only {f} in P2; is not enough {c} in P1 as (minimal) model?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `{c}` is not a model of `P1`.

---

In the case of ground (no variables) positive (all bodies positive) programs, the constraints are pretty simple:

1. For an interpretation to be a model of a ground positive program, every *applicable* rule must also be *applied*, where:

   - applicable: for ground positive programs, all literals in the body are contained in the interpretation,
   - applied: a head atom is contained the interpretation.
2. For a model to be an answer set, it has to be minimal among the set of all models of this program.

---

So, in `P1` you have this rule:

```
b :- c.
```

which, for the interpretation `{c}`, is applicable (since `c` is in the interpretation), but not applied (because `b` isn't).

As for `P2`, we have the fact `f.`, implying you have to have `f` in any answer set (since `f.` is the same `f :-`, meaning it's **always** applicable). However, `f` does not render the rule `b :- c` applicable, and there are no other rules, so `{f}` is a model of `P2`, and obviously also a minimal one - an answer set.

Because of that, e.g. `{c,b,f}` is not an answer set of `P2`, since it's not minimal when compared with `{f}`.

Comment: Ok thank you, so in P1 i have to include 'b' in the answer set because the body of the first rule b :- c (that is c) is contained in the interpretation {c}, am I right?

Comment: @Giac1: exactly. Essentially for ground positive normal (1 literal in head) programs you can build the answer set (for those programs, there's always exactly 1 AS), by starting with including the facts in the interpretation, and adding more literals until all applicable rules are applied.